# AWS EFS policy to restrict access by resource tags

Tags: terraform, amazon-efs

Is there anyway to restrict AWS EFS based on resource tags? I'm using below condition on the policy but i get error "mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting" when i try to mount on my ec2 instances.

```
resource "aws_efs_file_system_policy" "this" {
    file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.this.id
    policy = jsonencode({
        Version = "2012-10-17"
        Statement = [{
            Effect    = "Allow",
            Principal = "*",
            Action    = var.efs_client_actions,
            Resource = aws_efs_file_system.this.arn,
            Condition = {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/${var.efs_tag_key}" : var.efs_tag_value
                }
            }
        }]
    })
}
```

I even tried with "aws:ResourceTag/${var.efs_tag_key}" : var.efs_tag_value"
and "ec2:RequestTag/${var.efs_tag_key}" : var.efs_tag_value"

noting worked, any suggestions appreciated. Thank you!

I even tried with "aws:ResourceTag/${var.efs_tag_key}" : var.efs_tag_value"
and "ec2:RequestTag/${var.efs_tag_key}" : var.efs_tag_value"

but i get this error:
"mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting"